The site logo for the third time
I know this has been brought up at least twice before: the site logo.
Or, more generally, this site's overall design.
There was
Any ideas for a logo?
and
Could we get a logo for our stack exchange?
Both questions were answered with the site being in beta.
Now that that's not the case any more, can we start the discussion once more?
Do you have any ideas for a site logo?
Do you have ideas how this site's overall design could be customized to be more vi-like?
On Meta SE, the following resources may be relevant.
This (a little bit dated) question suggesting that we as the community should get the ball rolling.
And this answer promising a design overhaul for this site (among others) in 2022 (did I miss it?)
So ... let's make some noise and hope somebody at SE HQ hears us?
My ultimate point is: Emacs SE has a custom design.
This means the only thing you can do with Emacs you can't do with Vim is getting a SE site logo.
Really, can we leave it at that?

Ideas so I can post answers later: :wq, the V of the Vim logo, :vi

I'm don't really know much about UI (or UX as they call it these days).
Instead of pushing my own and flawed design ideas, I want to collect some things that are instantly recognizable as "vi" by people who know it.
I do like the ideas D. Ben Knoble brought up in his comment.
Something like :wq! (with or without the exclamation mark) is a frequent command.
It starts with a colon and ends with an exclamation mark, it's typical.
Using :vi is also a nice idea.
Can we think of some more Ex commands that are used out of context or just made-up?
To pay homage to my favorite command, I'd say :s/question/answer/ but it's much too long for a lame joke nobody will get.
We could also leave out the command itself and go for :%!. It looks just like an Ex command—or as if somebody swears in a comic book.
The V shape is obviously a design feature one could use.
The navigation keys hjkl are instantly recognizable as "vi" (and you see many so-called "vi modes" out there where they are the only feature sigh).
Can we turn that into a logo?
 k                    k
h l      - or -      hjl
 j

I'd want to keep the design independent from any one vi implementation.
We have questions about Neovim, Vim, vi and the occasional VSCodeVim (until we scare them away) and probably several others.
I would not want the design to favor any of these.
Specific colors won't cut it in my opinion because there exist soooo many colorschemes.
Having said that, the Vim logo features a green diamond and the Neovim logo is blue and green.
To contradict my previous paragraph, green seems to be a color Vim flavors can agree on.
Or, let's have the entire site in Solarized! (no, I'm just kidding)
GVim has a reputation of not being the most polished graphical program out there.
Even Neovim users complain that it's not shiny enough.
And let's not even start with the TUI versions.
A good designer may come up with ways to make this site look a bit retro without making it look old or boring.
The important thing is not to overdo it, I think.

For the Logo I believe it should make reference to both the Vim logo and the Neovim logo.
Remark:

The Neovim SE tag is the most popular tag in recent years by far.
The growth of GitHub stars for Neovim is also about three the one of Vim.

